# select count(*) from select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get row count from the following query. I get only row count as 1 but there are 35 records. Could you please let me know how to get the count from inner query?

Thank you

```
SELECT COUNT(*)(SELECT DISTINCT a.my_id, a.last_name, a.first_name, b.temp_val
                FROM Table_A a INNER JOIN Table_B b on a.a_id = b.a_id)
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You're missing a FROM and you need to give the subquery an alias.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT a.my_id, a.last_name, a.first_name, b.temp_val
   FROM dbo.Table_A AS a 
   INNER JOIN dbo.Table_B AS b 
   ON a.a_id = b.a_id
) AS subquery;
```

Comment: Any ideas on why the OP's original query was valid syntax? I would have bet the farm that it wouldn't compile much less run.

Comment: @ConradFrix i thought so too, and I was going to suggest as much, but I'm typing from an iPad and it is more cumbersome so I've been trying to keep things terse. So much for that. :-)

Comment: 'select count(*)' is odd w/o a table, but it's valid and returns 1.  Once we accept that, the second expression resolved as a 2nd column in the result set.

Comment: @ConradFrix `select count(*)` returns `1` in t-sql... even with no `from` clause.  So the query he posted had 2 result sets, one with a single row / value of 1, and then the second result set of his distinct query.

Comment: @EBarr it would have only been a second column if there was a comma in there. Can't test Michael's theory at the moment.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Ah. I had checked `SELECT COUNT(*)(SELECT number FROM master..spt_values)` on SQLFiddle and it doesn't support multiple result sets. Once I checked it elsewhere it made sense thanks

Comment: @AaronBertrand You can see it on [this data.se query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68938/weird-syntax)  if you [choose text-only results](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74289/add-support-for-multiple-results-sets-in-data-explorer)

Comment: Ah, the joys of a language that doesn't require statement termination. All hail semi-colons!

Comment: I soooooo inserted my own comma...duh.