# SELECT SUM() FROM (SELECT (SELECT ())

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a correct working T-SQL-script in this form

```
SELECT  columnA
        AS
        'numbers'
FROM    tableA
WHERE   clause
```

This script gives me as one column, called numbers, of integers. I want to sum these.

Calling the above lines 'script' I tried the following setup

```
SELECT  SUM(numbers)
FROM    (
            script
        )
```

Reading [select count(*) from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439122/select-count-from-select) I supposed this to work, however, it does not. I keep getting "Incorrect syntax near."

I do not know if it is important but that is here named columnA is itself maked by a SELECT statement.

Comment: You seem to be misusing the term "script". Could you post the *exact* query you're using, and the *exact* error it gives you?

Comment: I am surprised the first query doesn't throw an error. Single quotes are for string literals, but you are using them to create an alias name. `AS 'numbers'` should just be `AS numbers`. If you want to use delimiters (but I see no reason for doing so), this would be `AS [numbers]` in SQL Server and `AS "numbers"` in standard SQL.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need an alias on the subquery:

```
SELECT  SUM(numbers)
FROM    
(
    script  -- your subquery will go here
) src   -- place an alias here
```

So your full query will be:

```
select sum(numbers)
from
(
   SELECT  columnA  AS numbers
   FROM    tableA
   WHERE   clause
) src
```

Comment: BTW, this is a tSQL problem. Oracle doesn't care if you alias your subquery. Not sure about MySQL or others, but tSQL requires an alias on all subqueries.

Comment: @Bill: Oracle does it wrongly there. It's not a problem to implement things right.

Comment: @Bill my preference is to alias all subqueries whether or not it is required.  It makes it much clearer as to where the data is coming from.

Answer (score 8):

There is absolutely no problem whatsoever to achieve what you want. We don't see your entier query, but the most common problem is people forget to add an alias to their nested `select` statement. Take a look at this sample that works perfectly :

```
select sum(col1) as sum1 
from ( select col1 
        from ( select 1 col1 union all select 2 union all select 3 ) tmp 
     ) tmp2
```

According to the OP, here is your final query :

```
SELECT  SUM(numbers)
FROM    (
            SELECT  columnA
                    AS
                   'numbers'
              FROM    tableA
             WHERE   clause
        ) tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(x.ColumnA) as ColumnName FROM
(SELECT ColumnA FROM TableName) x
```

Just remember you can't use an ORDER clause on the query inside the parenthesis.

Using an order clause will give you this error:

*Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 30 The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.*

Comment: `the query inside the parenthesis` would be called a "subquery" and in this case, a "derived table" as it is used in the FROM clause.