# Mysql count number of result with join

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE $media_table (
            `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `options` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
            `order_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
            `player_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`))


 CREATE TABLE $category_table ( 
            `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `category` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
            `media_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

I get id, options, category for rows matching category 'foo','bar'. I also use limit to get only x number of results.

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.options, ct.category
            FROM $media_table as mt
            LEFT JOIN $category_table as ct
            ON mt.id = ct.media_id 
            WHERE mt.player_id = %d AND ct.category IN ('foo','bar')
            GROUP BY ct.media_id 
            ORDER BY mt.order_id
            LIMIT $limit
```

This works as intended. But I dont know how to get total number of results?

I tried this but the count is not correct.

```
SELECT COUNT(mt.id), ct.category
            FROM $media_table as mt
            LEFT JOIN $category_table as ct
            ON mt.id = ct.media_id 
            WHERE mt.player_id = %d AND ct.category IN ('foo','bar')
            GROUP BY ct.media_id
```

Where I select all results without the limit (in my previous query) the count is correct.

If I had only one table with primary key id I would do this to get count:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table
```

I dont know how to apply the same to my query.

Edit:  I found my answer here [select count(*) from select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439122/select-count-from-select)

Comment: I don't really see the problem, what do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: quit the left join or change it into an `inner join`, depending on your needs

Comment: you can see I use limit in my query to get x number of results (which is working), but I also need to know how to get total number of results

Comment: pleae read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edot pur question

Comment: When you say "I tried this", what'd it do? Did you get errors? Did you get the count? the count of the ID would be the number of your results.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Are you looking at the raw results of the query using a tool like phpMyAdmin or MySQL WorkBency or what?

Question 2: Will the ultimate query results be delivered to the client via a web browser or what?

Answer 1: "The SUM() function returns the total sum of a numeric column."

SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE condition;

Answer Possibility 2: If the results will be delivered in a web browser you should be able to use PHP or some other server side language like MS Active Server Pages to add up he "COUNT" field of each result.

Answer Possibility 3: Alternative 1: Export the results to a CVS file and import into a spreadsheet.

Maybe some of these suggestions will get the wheels turning and help you find the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I dont need sum, I want count (num_rows) but when I try my query in phpmyadmin it returns id and category rows instead of count how many results.

Comment: $num_rows_all = mysqli_num_rows($result);